# Trying to understand example of Erdmann and Wildon's Intro to lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

This is example 10.8 (ii) from Erdmann and Wildon's Intro to Lie Algebras

Hello everyone. I tried to give as much context as possible for this, but I'm hoping somebody will know what I'm talking about as this is all standard material in a first course on Lie algebras.

Let $sl(\alpha)$ is the root space of $\alpha$ which I have shown is isomorphic to $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$. Let $H$ be a Cartan subalgebra of some Lie algebra $L$.

Let $U = H + sl(\alpha)$. Let $K = ker(\alpha) \subset H$. By the rank-nullity formula, $dim K = dim H - 1$ (we know that dim $im(\alpha) = 1$ as $\alpha(h_\alpha) \neq 0$. As $H$ is abelian, $[h_\alpha,x] = 0$ for all $x \in K$. I have also shown that $[e_\alpha,x]=0$ and $[f_\alpha,x]=0$.

Thus every element of $sl(\alpha)$ acts trivially on $K$. It follows that $U = K \oplus sl(\alpha)$ is a decompositoin of $U$ into $sl(\alpha)$-modules. I have also shown that the adjoint representatoin of $sl(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $V^2$, the vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree 2 in 2 indeterminants. Thus $U$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of dim$H$-1 copies of the trivial representation, $V_0$, and one copy of the adjoint represntation, $V_2$

I'm confused on how we get $U = K \oplus sl(\alpha)$. We know $K$ and $sl(\alpha)$ are disjoint because the action is trivial? Also how do we know that $K$ decomposes into 1-dimensional trivial representations??

If anyone has more general insight into this example or specific answers to my questions I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: $sl(\alpha)$ is most probably not "the root space of $\alpha$" (which would be one-dimensional). Rather, I assume if $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha := \{x \in \mathfrak{g}: \forall h \in H : [h,x] =\alpha(h) x \}$ is the actual root space of $\alpha$, the thing that is isomorphic to $sl_2$ is $sl(\alpha):= \mathfrak{g}_\alpha + \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha} + [\mathfrak{g}_\alpha, \mathfrak{g}_{-\alpha}]$, where the last bracket is a one-dimensional subspace of $H$, presumably spanned by the element you call $h_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show, not that $K$ and $sl(\alpha)$ are "disjoint", but that they have intersection $K \cap sl(\alpha) =\{0\}$: Using the description of $sl(\alpha)$ in my comment, first see what $H \cap sl(\alpha)$ is (this intersection should be a one-dimensional space) and then check for which elements $x$ of this space we have $\alpha(x)=0$.

To see that $K$ decomposes into trivial $sl(\alpha)$-modules: I hope you have a grasp of the basic representation theory of $sl_2$, because then all you need to show is that the element $h_\alpha \in sl(\alpha)$ acts with eigenvalue $0$, in other words trivially, on $K$. Which should be hard not to show.