# Proof Explanation on proposition for root spaces of a finite dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, lie-algebras

Introduction to Lie Algebras K. Erdmann and M. Wildon page 100:

> Proposition 10.9: Let $\alpha \in \Phi$, where $\Phi$ is the collection of all roots for Lie algebra $L$ with Cartan Subalgebra $H$. The root space $L_{\pm \alpha}$ are 1 dimensional. Moreover, the only multiples of $\alpha$ which lie in $\Phi$ are ${\pm \alpha}$. Let $h_\alpha$ be the semisimple basis element of $sl(\alpha) \cong sl(2,\mathbb{C})$

(I bolded the parts of the proof I am having trouble understanding)

> proof:
> If $c\alpha$ is a root, then $h_\alpha$ takes $c\alpha(h_\alpha)=2c$ as an eigenvalue. As the eigenvalues of $h_\alpha$ are integral, either $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ or $c \in \mathbb{Z} + \frac{1}{2}$. To rule out the unwanted values for $c$, we consider the root string module:
>
> $M = H \oplus (\oplus_{c\alpha} L_{c\alpha})$
>
> Let $K = ker\alpha \subset H$ (it is possible that $K=H$).
>
> By an example on the previous page, $K \oplus sl(\alpha)$ is an $sl(\alpha)$-submodule of $M$. By Weyl's Theorem, modules for $sl(\alpha)$ are completely reducible, so we may write:
>
> $M = K \oplus sl(\alpha) \oplus W$
>
> Where $W$ is a complementary submodule.
>
> **If either of the conclusions of the proposition are false, then $W$ is non-zero**. Let $V \cong V_s$ be an irreducible submodule of $W$. If $s$ is even, then it follows from the classification of chapter 8 that $V$ contains an $h_\alpha$-eigenvector with eigenvalue 0. Call this eigenvector $v$. The zero-eigenspace of $h_\alpha$ on $M$ is $H$, **which is contained in $K \oplus sl(\alpha)$**. Hence $v \in (K \oplus sl(\alpha)) \cap V = 0$, which is a contradiction.
>
> Before considering the case where $s$ is odd, we pursue another consequence of this argument. Suppose that $2 \alpha \in \Phi$. Then $h_\alpha$ has $2\alpha(h_\alpha)=4$ as an eigenvalue. As the eigenvalues of $h_\alpha$ on $K \oplus sl(\alpha)$ are $0$ and $\pm 2$, the only way this could happen is if $W$ contains an irreducible submodule $V_s$ with $s$ even, which we just saw is impossible.
>
> Now suppose that $s$ is odd. Then $V$ must contain and $h_\alpha$-eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. As $\alpha(h_\alpha)=2$, this implies that $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ is a root of $L$. But then both $\frac{1}{2}\alpha$ and $\alpha$ are roots of $L$, **which contradicts the previous paragraph**.

Comment: Wait, how is $sl(\alpha)$ actually defined at this point? Because I think in my comment and answer to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3880498/96384 I assumed we already know the root space to $\alpha$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: Given a root $\alpha$, we take $x \in L_\alpha$. It has been shown that $\exists y \in L_{-\alpha}$ s.t. span$\{x,y,[x,y]\}$ $\cong sl(2,\mathbb{C})$. We denote $span\{x,y,[x,y]\}$ as $sl(\alpha)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If either of the conclusions ...":
If the dimension of $L_\alpha$ is $\ge 2$, the eigenspace to the eigenvalue $2$ of $h_\alpha$ on $M$ has dimension $\ge 2$. But its eigenspace to the eigenvalue $2$ on $K\oplus sl(\alpha)$ only has dimension ...

If there is $c\neq \pm1$ with $L_{c\alpha} \neq 0$, then there is a nonzero $x\in L_{c\alpha} \subseteq M$ with $[h_\alpha, x] = 2cx$. But the only eigenvalues of $h_\alpha$ on $K\oplus sl(\alpha)$ are ...

"which is contained in ...": How large can $dim(H)-dim(K)$ at most be? And $sl(\alpha)$ contains the element $h_\alpha$ which is in $H$ but not in $K$.

"which contradicts the previous paragraph": If $\alpha$ and $\frac12 \alpha$ are both roots, then for the root $\beta := \frac12 \alpha$ we also have $2\beta$ as a root. But the previous paragraph showed that for *any* root, its double is not a root.